# Plsql anonymous block not showing output

Tags: plsql

I have a strange issue.
In an anonymous block I have multiple dbms_output.put_line statements to see how far my code executes smoothly. 
When i am running it on plsql developer the block is running for an indefinite time and , i can see the output in the output tab only when I terminate it . Is there any way I can see the output in parallel to the execution in plsql developer ?

Comment: No. Run the code in sqldeveloper debugger.

Comment: Looks like the question is more like *"How to get dbms_output before the PL/SQL call completes"*. Otherwise it looks like all of the questions about enabling server output.

Comment: By the way, [PL/SQL Developer also has a debugger](https://www.allroundautomations.com/plsdebugger.html) ;)

Comment: Exactly William.. sorry maybe I did not put across my question properly... I am exactly looking for what you said . I need the dbms_output before the PL/SQL call completes in PLSQL developer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use dbms_application_info package and see session information from v$session or gv$session.

See https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_appinf.htm#ARPLS003